# Como calcular a soma/subtração cumulativa dos registros anteriores em SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando, sem sucesso, criar uma coluna `SALDO` para poder acompanhar o saldo do Fluxo de Caixa. Imaginei fazer isso no SQL mesmo, gerando uma coluna que calculasse o saldo.

Para isso, preciso ter acesso ao registro anterior, para poder fazer a operação de soma ou desconto, baseado no tipo de movimento (`tipo`).

A estrutura é de apenas uma tabela, com o campo `valor` e com o campo `tipo`, que pode ser `E` (entrada, soma) ou `S` (saída, subtrai).

```
SELECT lct.id, lct.descricao, 
       DATE_FORMAT (lct.data,'%d/%m/%Y') as "data", 
       lct.tipo, 
       CONCAT('R$ ', FORMAT(lct.valor,2,'de_DE')) as "valor", 
       emp.descricao as "empreendimento", 
       cat.descricao as "categoria",
       con.descricao as "conta",
       cax.descricao as "caixa"
       FROM empreendimentos emp, contas con, 
       lancamentos lct, concategorias cat, caixas cax
       WHERE lct.idconta = con.id 
       AND lct.idempreendimento = emp.id 
       AND lct.idcategoria = cat.id
       AND lct.idcaixa = cax.id
       AND cax.id = 1
       AND lct.flagstatus = 1
       ORDER BY lct.data ASC, lct.id
```

Dado o código acima, seria possível realizar o que preciso?

Comment: Para "registro anterior" lag e lead ... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

Comment: Motta, bom dia!

Infelizmente a minha hospedagem atual não possui a versão 8 do MySQL instalada, então não tenho acesso a essas funções.

Comment: Um subselect ou uma function retornando o valor , outra opção seria uma montar uma tabela de fluxo de caixa via procedure , atualizar via procedure (usando um event) e ler desta tabela , o que me ocorre agora.

Comment: Ótimas dicas, mas sem um exemplo eu não consigo chegar, não conheço o suficiente.

Comment: Você conseguiu e aprendeu um pouco !

Comment: Verdade, esse era o objetivo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver utilizando o seguinte:

```
    SELECT sld.data,
       sld.tipo,
       CONCAT('R$ ', FORMAT(sld.valor,2,'de_DE')) as "valor",       
       CASE
          WHEN sld.tipo = 'S'
          THEN
            CONCAT('R$ ', FORMAT(@running_total:=@running_total - sld.valor,2,'de_DE'))
          ELSE
            CONCAT('R$ ', FORMAT(@running_total:=@running_total + sld.valor,2,'de_DE')) 
      END  
      AS cumulative_sum     
FROM
(SELECT lct.id, lct.descricao, 
  lct.data as "data", 
  lct.tipo as "tipo", 
  lct.valor as "valor",   
  emp.descricao as "empreendimento", 
  cat.descricao as "categoria",
  con.descricao as "conta",
  cax.descricao as "caixa"
  FROM empreendimentos emp, contas con, 
  lancamentos lct, concategorias cat, caixas cax
  WHERE lct.idconta = con.id 
  AND lct.idempreendimento = emp.id 
  AND lct.idcategoria = cat.id
  AND lct.idcaixa = cax.id
  AND cax.id = 1
  AND lct.flagstatus = 1
  GROUP BY lct.id
  ORDER BY lct.data) sld
JOIN (SELECT @running_total:=0) r
ORDER BY sld.data;
```

Utilizando variáveis, consegui chegar ao resultado esperado:

```
(data, tipo, valor, cumulative_sum) VALUES
('02/01/2021 00:00:00', 'E', 'R$ 253.571,83', 'R$ 253.571,83'), 
('02/01/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 200,00', 'R$ 253.371,83'), 
('04/01/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 930,05', 'R$ 252.441,78'), 
('04/01/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 2.317,38', 'R$ 250.124,40'), 
('05/01/2021 00:00:00', 'E', 'R$ 3.000,00', 'R$ 253.124,40'), 
('05/01/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 25,80', 'R$ 253.098,60'), 
('11/01/2021 00:00:00', 'E', 'R$ 3.000,00', 'R$ 256.098,60'), 
('15/01/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 2.000,00', 'R$ 254.098,60'), 
('22/01/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 199,99', 'R$ 253.898,61'), 
('22/01/2021 00:00:00', 'E', 'R$ 2.000,00', 'R$ 255.898,61'), 
('29/01/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 213,58', 'R$ 255.685,03'), 
('03/02/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 979,00', 'R$ 254.706,03'), 
('03/02/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 27,70', 'R$ 254.678,33'), 
('05/02/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 206,00', 'R$ 254.472,33'), 
('17/02/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 1.841,00', 'R$ 252.631,33'), 
('03/03/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 25,80', 'R$ 252.605,53'), 
('03/03/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 979,00', 'R$ 251.626,53'), 
('05/03/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 206,38', 'R$ 251.420,15'), 
('09/03/2021 00:00:00', 'E', 'R$ 3.000,00', 'R$ 254.420,15'), 
('31/03/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 1.356,00', 'R$ 253.064,15'), 
('01/04/2021 00:00:00', 'E', 'R$ 2.000,00', 'R$ 255.064,15'), 
('05/04/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 25,80', 'R$ 255.038,35'), 
('05/04/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 979,00', 'R$ 254.059,35'), 
('08/04/2021 00:00:00', 'E', 'R$ 3.000,00', 'R$ 257.059,35'), 
('09/04/2021 00:00:00', 'E', 'R$ 2.000,00', 'R$ 259.059,35'), 
('09/04/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 209,00', 'R$ 258.850,35'), 
('27/04/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 294,34', 'R$ 258.556,01'), 
('27/04/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 10.500,00', 'R$ 248.056,01'), 
('28/04/2021 00:00:00', 'S', 'R$ 42,09', 'R$ 248.013,92')
```

Fonte da ideia: https://popsql.com/learn-sql/mysql/how-to-calculate-cumulative-sum-running-total-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função `SUM` para isso, combinando com o `CASE WHEN` para:

- CASE tipo_movimento = 'E' soma "valor"
- ELSE (caso contário) soma "- valor", ou seja, subtrai quando for "S"

Aqui um exemplo dessa parte, tentei usar os nomes semelhantes aos da sua tabela:

```
SELECT lct.id_conta,
       SUM(CASE WHEN lct.tipo_movimento = 'E' 
                THEN lct.valor 
                ELSE - lct.valor 
           END) AS saldo
FROM lancamentos lct
GROUP BY lct.id_conta
```

Basta adicioar os outros campos e tabelas da sua query. Note que, como o saldo dever ser calculado por conta, adicionei "id_conta" ao `GROUP BY`, caso contrário ira misturar as contas calculando errado o saldo.

Pode ver funcionando aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c37dd/1

Comment: Ricardo, bom dia!

Essa função sugerida apenas marca o registro como positivo ou negativo. O que preciso é calcular o saldo, descontando ou somando o valor atual com o valor anterior, criando um valor cumulativo.

Comment: Ela atualiza o saldo, mas de maneira agrupada... a necessidade aqui é de mostrar o saldo linha a linha, compreende?